# Angular 2 Basic Obsverable Subscribe pattern

Tags: php, angular

I'm trying to access data from a JSON encoded PHP script API like this:

```
export class AppComponent {
    test = 'Angular is live';

    private data;

    constructor(private http:Http) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.getData();
    }

    getData() {
        console.log('-- GETTING DATA --');

        // DATA GRABBING PATTERN
        this.
        http.
        get('https://localhost:3000/sampleData.php').
        subscribe(
            function(response) {
                res => this.data = res.json()
            },
            function(error) {
                console.log('error grabbing the data');
            },
            function() { // COMPLETE
                console.log('grabbing data is complete');
                console.log(this.data); // WHY IS THIS RETURNING UNDEFINED?
            }
        );
        console.log(this.data);
    }
}
```

Everywhere I output `console.log(this.data)` I get un-defined, however when I access the variable `{{data}}` in the template it outputs the data just fine.

How do I know when the observable has finished grabbing data? Or am I thinking of this wrong?

Here is the sampleData.php file:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    $data = array(
        array('id' => '1','first_name' => 'Cynthia'),
        array('id' => '2','first_name' => 'Keith'),
        array('id' => '3','first_name' => 'Robert'),
        array('id' => '4','first_name' => 'Theresa'),
        array('id' => '5','first_name' => 'Margaret')
    );

    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment: You seem to have an odd mix of arrow functions `() => {}` and old-fashioned `function () {}`, I'm surprised that works at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `arrow functions` instead of functions to conserve `this` property.

```
    subscribe(
         (res) => { this.data = res.json() } ,
        (error) => {
            console.log('error grabbing the data');
        },
        ()=> { // COMPLETE
            console.log('grabbing data is complete');
            console.log(this.data); // WHY IS THIS RETURNING UNDEFINED?
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to keep `this` pointing to the current class instance

```
    subscribe(
        response => this.data = response.json(),
        error => {
            console.log('error grabbing the data');
        },
        () => { 
            console.log('grabbing data is complete');
            console.log(this.data); // WHY IS THIS RETURNING UNDEFINED?
        }
```

It's only necessary where you need to use `this` but it can be used everywhere and is less error prone if you use it consistently.

Comment: when you do this:
`response =>` is that the same as `function(response) {` I guess i'm a little confused on the syntax here

Comment: Not sure what part confuses you. `response => this.data = response.json();` is the same as `response => { return this.data = response.json(); }` is similar to `function (response) { return this.data = response.json() }`. The `return` is redundant here but I added to emphasise that the short form without `{}` implicitly returns the result.